# Calling as2 function from as3 swf

Tags: flash

I have an old piece of AS2 based SWF file, which has several global defined functions inside. When I load it into an AS3 SWF, I get the following error:

`Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 9  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method startDancing through a reference with static type flash.display:AVM1Movie.`

I load the as2 based swf the followig way:

```
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
mLoader.load(new URLRequest("s.swf"));

function onCompleteHandler(evt:Event)
{
    var embedSWF:AVM1Movie = AVM1Movie(evt.target.content);
    addChild(embedSWF);
    embedSWF.startDancing();
    trace('asd');
}
```

startDancing is defined globally in the first frame of the AS2 SWF file. How can I call its method?

Answer (score 1):

Some option

- check if your startDancing must be a public method
- use AVM2Loader http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/AVM2Loader/src/net/fladdict/display/AVM2Loader.as
  this will hack at loadTime your avm1 movie
- or finally you can create a local connection
  AS2 and AS3 can talk trought this channel ^^
  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_fr/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html